# Show in the google search Official website

Tags: wordpress, title, google-search

Good morning,

At the moment when I am trying to search for our website it appears the next:

griotblues.com: Front Page

griotblues.com/

In the google search.

I would like to have something like this:

Official

tinariwen.com/

But I actually don't know where do I need to change that information.

I am using wordpress and the theme call DIVI, tried to change the title of that page, but nothing actually happened.

Looking for some help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you would like to use yoast SEO plugin, it will help. Also follow https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en this one.

Comment: Good plugin, thank you.